# Props not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, next.js

I am getting error in all my functions stating that the props are not defined. The error is on the word "props" for the following functions"

> function PostButton(props)
>       function PostButton2(props)
>       function TotalVotes(props) 
>       function Post(props) {
>       function CommentList(props)

I do not want to avoid this warning using any keyword. What would be my props here?

Comment: What exactly is the warning message?

Comment: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type. @JoãoCunha.

Comment: @Rebel if you're using typescript and have strict checking rules enabled in your `eslint` you have to defined types for all your props. or you have to disable the eslint rule for not accepting `any` types

Answer (score 0):

If you're using typescript and have strict checking rules enabled in your `eslint` you have to defined types for all your props. or you have to disable the `eslint` rule for not accepting any type:

```
interface Props {
  handleclick: () =>,
  text: string,
  upvote: () =>,
}
```

So you could try something like this to define your types. Then you can pass then on every use of the `props` variable like:

```
CommentList(props: Props)
```

Comment: Not just eslint, if you have noImplicitAny turned on in your typescript settings then it won't even *compile*.